# jqgrid disable an html button in loadComplete event

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, jquery-1.6

I have a jqgrid in my page and outside the grid there is a button like the following:

```
<input type="button" id="mybutton" value="click here" />
```

On document ready I am disabling and hiding the button with the following code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var btn = $('#mybutton');
    btn.prop('disabled', true);
    btn.hide();
    ...
    setupGrid();
});
```

`setupGrid()` is a function wich does the jqgrid setup and has this code in the `loadComplete` event

```
[...]
loadComplete: function() {
    //do some logic here and then...
    var btn = $('#mybutton');
    if ( mycustomlogic ) {
        btn.prop('disabled', false);
        btn.show();        
    }
}
```

but unfortunately the button is not enabled again after that. It is correctly showed when `mycustomlogic` evaluate to true but it remains in disabled state.
I have also tried to use `btn.attr('disabled', 'disabled')` and `btn.removeAttr('disabled')` instead of `.prop()` with no luck.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Have you tried `.removeProp('disabled')`?

Comment: @darkajax don't use removeProp!! unless you plan on never using that property again.  Anyways .prop() should be working since it worked to disable the button.  Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: No. I am getting stuck with this. The console does not report any error or warning...

Comment: @Lorenzo is it a jQuery button or just a regular input button?

Comment: @wirey: it is a jQuery button. Do you think I should use `btn.button('enable')` instead?

Comment: @Lorenzo yes.. you need to use the api's methods.. since jQuery will not refresh the button state automatically for you.. You might have to use button('refresh') also to refresh the state

Comment: @Lorenzo wait.. you can use one or the other.. if using .prop() - then you need to refresh state.. or you can just use .button('enable/disable')

Comment: You're right. Good catch. Simple enough to understand that I need a pause :) If you want me to accept the answer just write it down. Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using jQuery UI buttons, it's best to use the api's methods to enable/disable the buttons http://api.jqueryui.com/button/

```
$(element).button('disable/enable')
```

That way it handles all the other changes for you besides just the disabled property